Difference would and will
I want to understand the use of "would" in this sentence. What differentiates with "will?"

I think you’ll find that the definite article is dropped if the
nickname is an extension of the town it relates to. Obviously Wolves
is a shortened version of Wolverhampton, and you’d never refer to
“The” Wolverhampton. Similarly, West Ham United are known as “The
Irons”, and you would refer to them as “The” Irons, but just “United”,
where United is an extension of the town name, West Ham. Referring to
“The United” would be the equivalent of referring to “The West Ham” or
“The Dallas


I'm sure this is a duplicate of another question about this use of "would". But "would" is used to describe hypothetical behaviour ("if you wanted to refer to them, you would refer to them as...") Whereas "will" is wrong because it sounds more like a command; "would" is general timewise, while "will" refers either to the future or giving an order ("You will do what I tell you").

This question is similar to: Verb tenses when using will/would?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

'Would', when used in the future tense, is subjunctive. That means it suggests what is possible rather than what definitely will happen.
Your example text is saying how to refer to football teams by their nicknames. It rightly uses "you would refer to them...." because there's no saying that you ever will refer to them. You might read this interesting fact about West Ham United and then never speak about them again. Saying "you will refer to them as..." sounds like an order.

Do you mean "would" means "possible" and "will" definitely will happen? I'm a bit confused here. Can you explain?

@Shakila Almost - 'would' indicates what will happen in hypothetical situations, rather than just what is 'possible'. For what is only possible it's more likely we'd use "might". For example: 1. If I win some money I might buy a new car (possibility) 2. If I won some money I would buy a new car (hypothetical) 3. When I receive my inheritance I will buy a new car (definite intention).

Thanks. Your sentence uses "would" in we'd use, why do you use "would" rather than "will?" I usually say we will use.

@Shakila We would use it if we had to. You might never need to. Only use 'will' if there is a definite scenario upcoming in which you will.

Thanks a lot, Atralbee. Can you give an example sentence "will" in a definite scenario upcoming? I'd like to be clearer with the scenario.

@Shakila Example 1: "When I visit Disneyland next month I will go on all the rollercoasters". There is a definite intention to visit a place (hence "when") so the details are what will happen. Example 2: "If I got the chance to go to Disneyland I would go on all the rollercoasters". Visiting is a hypothetical, so the details are what would happen if the hypothetical became reality.

Can you explain how "would" works in sentence B when aswering an A's question? A:   What's the meaning of "hair off?" Dave tries to shoot a kid in car's trunk to lure out Robert from hiding:
Dave: I was a hair off on that one. I might have hit the kid.
B: I would understand it to mean I (or my aim) was out by only a hair’s breadth. In other words, I very nearly shot the kid.
